# Issue with soap api ..invalid parameters

Tags: api, soap

I'm trying to send a SOAP request but I receive an error telling me that some parameters are invalid. Here's the code:

MY CODE :

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient('https://live.domainbox.net/?WSDL', array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
$params = array(
    'AuthenticationParameters' => array(
        'Reseller' => 'resellerid',
        'Username' => 'username',
        'Password' => 'password'
    ),
    'CommandParameters' => array(
        'DomainName' => 'mydomain.com',
        'LaunchPhase' => 'GA'
    )
);

$result = $client->CheckDomainAvailability($params);
print_r($result);

?>
```

Actual output should be like this

```
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance”
xmlns:xsd=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema” xmlns:soap12=”http://www.w3.org/2003/05/
soap-envelope”>
<soap12:Body>
    <CheckDomainAvailability xmlns=”https://live.domainbox.net/”>
        <AuthenticationParameters>
            <Reseller>myreseller</Reseller>
            <Username>myuser</Username>
            <Password>mypassword</Password>
        </AuthenticationParameters>
        <CommandParameters>
            <DomainName>checkadomain.co</DomainName>
            <LaunchPhase>GA</LaunchPhase>
        </CommandParameters>
    </CheckDomainAvailability>
</soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Error i am getting

```
stdClass Object ( [CheckDomainAvailabilityResult] => stdClass Object ( [ResultCode] => 201 [ResultMsg] => Invalid Authentication Parameters [TxID] => 0df56bb4-e5dc-439e-9ec9-8a3609f37d51 [AvailabilityStatus] => 3 [AvailabilityStatusDescr] => ErrorOccurred [LaunchPhase] => GA [DropDate] => [BackOrderAvailable] => [AdditionalResults] => stdClass Object ( ) ) )
```

I am newbie and i dosent any thing about php or api ..

i tried with all possible answers online ..but no luck

please kindly give me full code ..it will be helpful

Note : my login details were correct

Comment: Have the exact same problme. Did you fixed this problem? Was there a problem with the domainbox api?